# 613.org, 613db.org: what happened to it?

Tags: internet, music, chasidut-hasidism

There used to be a website, 613.org, with a huge trove of music and shiurim.  It got hacked at some point; the site was removed and access to the files was presented through 613db.org.  For the last year or so, however, 613db.org has been a parked domain.

Does anyone know what happened to it?  Did people simply stop paying for it, or did it move someplace else?

Comment: You can find the old site at the internet archive if you want. https://web.archive.org/web/20111229223856/http://613.org/

Comment: @Bachrach44, thank you for that!  I'd checked the Wayback for 613db.org and couldn't download anything, but I forgot to check it for the original site.  The .mp3's and .rm's at least are downloadable; I'm checking the .ram's to see if anything can be done.